# boto3 for cloudtrail lookupevents

Tags: python-3.x, boto3

*I am using boto3 for the first time and I am trying to filter the cloudtrail Eventhistory using boto3 lookupevents. First I need to filter it using the resource name and then filter using the EventName as RunInstances. From there I need to find the username. This is my code but somehow I am not able to get the right user who created the instance.*

```
 client = boto3.client('cloudtrail')
 paginator = client.get_paginator('lookup_events')
  page_iterator = paginator.paginate(
    LookupAttributes=[{'AttributeKey':'ResourceName','AttributeValue': 'i0...'}])
 for page in page_iterator:
    for event in page['Events']:
        page2_iterator=cloudtrail.lookup_events(LookupAttributes=[{'AttributeKey':'EventName', 'AttributeValue':'RunInstances'}])
        for i in page2_iterator:
            for event in i['Events']:
                username=event['Username']
                print(username)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you get the paginator back you already have all the events for that resource.  Now you just loop through the list and find the username that initiated the RunInstances like this:

```
import boto3
  
client = boto3.client('cloudtrail')
paginator = client.get_paginator('lookup_events')
page_iterator = paginator.paginate(LookupAttributes=[{'AttributeKey': 'ResourceName', 'AttributeValue': 'i-0b7c62b317938f671'}])
for page in page_iterator:
    for event in page['Events']:
        if event["EventName"] == "RunInstances":
            print(event["Username"])
```